# how to change the layout of everypage to give every question enough blank space?

Tags: exsheets

```
\documentclass[10pt,adobefonts]{article}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage[margin=.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{exsheets,mathpazo,titlesec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{diagbox}


%\Sample is defined to contain some sample text:
\def\sample{This is some sample text we will use to create a somewhat
longer text spanning a few lines.}
\def\Sample{\sample\ \sample\par\sample}
\setlength\parindent{0in}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large\mdseries\filcenter}{}{1em}{}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\newlength{\spacing}
\setlength{\spacing}{1in plus 1fil}
\settasks{
counter-format = tsk. ,
item-indent = 0em ,
label-width = 1em,
resume = true,
after-item-skip = \spacing,
after-skip = \spacing
}
\newcommand{\resetspacing}[1]{
\setlength{\spacing}{#1 plus 1fil}
\settasks{after-item-skip = \spacing,after-skip=\spacing}
}
\begin{document}
\section{课后自我检测习题}
\begin{tasks}
\task   （8分）某药业集团生产的某种药品包装盒的表面展开图如图标签所示.如果长方体盒子的长比宽多4cm，求这种药品包装盒的体积.\\


\task   （8分）某商场购进甲、乙两种服装后，都加价40\%标价出售."春节"期间商场搞优惠促销，决定将甲、乙两种服装分别按标价的八折和九折出售，某顾客购买甲、乙两种服装共付款182元，两种服装标价之和为210元，问这种服装的进价和标价各是多少？
\task   （8分）小明的爸爸骑摩托车带着小明在公路上行驶，小明第一次注意到路边里程碑上的数时，发现它是一个两位数且它的两个数字之和为9，刚好过1个小时，他发现路边里程碑上的数恰好是第一次看到的个位和十位数字颠倒后得到的，又过3小时，他发现里程碑上的数字比第一次看到的两位数中间多个0，你知道小明爸爸骑摩托车的速度是多少么？
\task   （10分）为庆祝“六一”儿童节，某市中小学统一组织文艺会演，甲、乙粮所学校共92人（其中甲校人数多余乙校人数，且驾校人数不够90人）准备统一购买服装参加演出，下面是某服装厂给出的演出服装的价格表：\\

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline

购买服装的套数 & 1套至45套 & 46套至90套 & 91套及以上\\ \hline
每套服装的价格 & 60元      & 50元       & 40元     \\ \hline
\end{tabular}\\
如果两所学校分别单独购买服装，一共应付5000元\\
(1)如果甲、乙两校联合起来购买服装，那么比各自购买服装共可节省多少钱？\\
(2)甲、乙两校各有多少名学生准备参加演出？\\
(3)如果甲校有10名同学调去参加书法绘画比赛不能参加演出，请为两校设计一种省钱的购买服装的方案.


\task  （10分）为调动销售人员的工作积极性，A、B两公司采取如下工资支付方式：A公司每月2000元基本工资，另加销售额的2\%作为奖金；B公司每月1600元基本工资，另加销售额的4\%作为奖金.已知A、B两公司两位销售员小李、小张1\~6月份的销售额如下表：\\

(1)请问小李于小张3月份的工资各是多少？\\
(2)小李1\~6月份的销售额$y_1=1200x+10400$，小张1\~6月份的销售额$y_2$也是月份$x$的一次函数，请求出$y_2$与$x$的函数关系式.\\
(3)如果7\~12月份两人的销售额也分别满足(2)中两个一次函数的关系,问:几月份起小张的工资高于小李的工资？
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As I see it this question is rather about the [`tasks`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tasks) package than about `exsheets`.

Comment: BTW: using a `tasks` list that isn't multi-columned is a bit pointless (except for consistent layout when you *have* a multi-columned list somewhere else in your document). I'd rather use `enumitem`'s power with en `enumerate` list...